# Jasper Reports: page x of y within one record

Tags: jasper-reports

I have report with multiple records, where one record is consisting of 1-5 pages. How to display `"page x of y"`, where `x` is a number of page for actual record and `y` is total pages for actual record ? I have something like below for `x` variable (reset on new record, incremet by page), but it doesn't work (on each page x have 1 value):

```
<variable name="x" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="report_count" incrementType="Page" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(1)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>

<!-- group by record -->
<group name="report_count" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></groupExpression>
</group>

<textField evaluationTime="Now" evaluationGroup="report_count">
    <reportElement x="141" y="5" width="156" height="20"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{x}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `calculation="count"` does not do what you are expecting it to. It returns the count of non-null values that your `variableExpression` returns. As your `variableExpression` only returns a single value, the variable is always set to 1.

An easy solution is to set the calculation type to `"Nothing"`, and the variableExpression to `$V{x}+1`

i.e:

```
<variable name="x" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="report_count" incrementType="Page" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{x} + 1]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(1)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

---

### Edit: Alternative solution

The `group` tag can have the attribute `isResetPageNumber`. When set to true it will reset the built-in variable `PAGE_NUMBER` at the start of every group. As you are already grouping by each record, I think this should give you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't using "Sum" be a good solution as well? I didn't quite understand the question, so I didn't give this suggestion. (Congrats on 1,000)

Comment: One problem with that: `incrementType="Page"` doesn't work. incrementing is by record. Why ?

Comment: @mdahlman: Yes, I think calculation="Sum" would work, but I had to refer to the documentation to be sure. As some of the calculation types don't work intuitively (and I never remember which) I tend to avoid them altogether.

Comment: @marioosh: I'm not sure why that would be the case. Possibly an incompatibility with the group `isStartNewPage` option?? You'd have to experiment to find out.